# Use "In" clause entity framework

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework

```
Dim objModel As New HireBPCEntities
Dim SuspenseEntry = From M In objModel.tblSuspenseEntries Where strIDsToApprove.Contains(M.ID)

 For Each Entry In SuspenseEntry.ToList()

    Dim tblSE As tblSuspenseEntry = DirectCast(Entry, tblSuspenseEntry)
    tblSE.Exclude_YN = "N"
   //Some other code
   objModel.SaveChanges()
Next
```

Here strIDsToApprove is comma sep values. 
i.e strIDsToApprove = "1,2,4,7"  Or sometimes strIDsToApprove ="12" (User can select one or multiple Records)

**My problem is** When strIDsToApprove ="12" then LINQ gets 3 records with *ID 1,2 AND 12* if I use Contains in above Code. I -only - need Record with ID "12" in this case.

**This is equivalent to SQL**
  select * from tblSuspenseEntry
  where ID in (12) 
  --which gives one row back with ID=12

What Am I missing here? How can I write "IN" Clause using Entity Framework.

Comment: `strIDsToApprove` should be a parsed array of the integers, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

The `Contains` method acts the same as the `In` keyword for `sql`.

```
Dim matches() As Integer = {1, 2, 12}
Dim query = tblSuspenseEntry.Where(Function(o) matches.Contains(o.Id)).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

Match the data type of M.ID field to strIDsToApprove. Mixing and matching integers and strings give this type of issues.